# Overlapping column in Wordpress Gutenburg

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Is there a way to overlap column in gutenberg? I have used different block editor plugins like Getwin & Kadance Blocks, but I can't get it done in both.

I have outlined an example below.

[image]